# Does the Australia Post plugin calculate weight in shipping costs?

Tags: shipping, api

I am trying to find out if the Australia Post plugin takes into consideration the weight of the product(s) when calculating a shipping fee.

I have called AP but they have no idea. On example Magento site they have none of the products have a weight and its just a flat fee for shipping.

Has anyone used this plugin before? Does it calculate shipping rates taking into account weight?

Comment: Rather then posting this here, i suggest you should directly ask the extension company if they provide the things you want

Comment: @TBIInfotech yeah I tried that. They point blank refused to answer my questions :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does use weight and postcodes of source and destination addresses to calculate in real time using the AP api.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do it in multiple ways.
1) Use its API.
2) Use some [shipping extension](https://www.appjetty.com/magento-australia-post-shipping.htm).